# A cricket has taken a chunk out of my gecko's tail. What should I do?

Tags: behavior, health, safety, geckos, first-aid

As it turns out, I had way too many crickets in my gecko's terrarium and one of them had been eating away at her tail. It was just a little off the tip and I've taken the crickets out and I'll be hand feeding her/giving her less crickets at a time from now on. There is a bit of bone sticking out, but she seems to be getting around just fine. Is there anything else I should do or will it heal on its own?[image]